# Comparison test to check the nature of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

Reading my calculus notes I found the next example:

> To analyze the nature of the series
> $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^5+1}{6n^{10}+\sqrt[6]{n}}$$
> by the limit comparison test, a series that can be compared to $S$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}$

I don't understand how to arrive to such conclusion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which conclusion? That $\sum\frac1{n^4}$ is a good candidate or that applying the test actually works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By limit comparison test we have that

$$\frac{\frac{n^5+1}{6n^{10}+\sqrt[6]{n}}}{\frac1{n^4}}=\frac{n^9+n^4}{6n^{10}+\sqrt[6]{n}} \to 0$$

therefore the given series converges.

As an alternative by direct comparison test we have

$$\frac{n^5+1}{6n^{10}+\sqrt[6]{n}} \le \frac{n^5+n^5}{6n^{10}+0}=\frac13\frac1{n^5}$$

Answer (score 3):

The shortest method would use *asymptotic equivalence*  of functions. Namely as any polynomial is equivalent to its leading term, we have
$$n^5+1\sim_\infty n^5,\quad 6n^{10}+\sqrt[6]{n}\sim_\infty 6n^{10}, \quad\text{ therefore }\quad  \frac{n^5+1}{6n^{10}+\sqrt[6]{n}}\sim_\infty \frac{n^5}{6n^{10}}=\frac1{6n^5},$$
which is a convergent $p$-series.